# How to normalize my integer array from 0 to 10 in C

Tags: c, math, normalization

I have an array of integers ranging from some minimum to some maximum. I want to rescale them so that the minimum scales to 0, the maximum to 10, and in-between numbers scale to the nearest integer between 0 and 10, linearly.

There's no syntax error, but the code doesn't work as intended.

```
int main()
{
    int d,k,m;
int B[20];
int A[] = { -3, 200, -22, 4, 5, 300, 2, 5, 4, 5, -1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 4, 2, 0, 7, -3 };

int i = 0, j = 0;
int maxval = 0;
for (i=0; i<20; i++) 
{ 
    if (A[i] > maxval) 
    maxval = A[i]; 
}
int minval = maxval;
for (i=0; i<20; i++) 
{ 
    if (A[i] < minval) 
    minval=A[i];
}
d=(maxval-minval)/10;
printf("minval= %d\nmaxval= %d\nd=%d ", minval, maxval, d);



for (i=0; i<20; i++) 
{   m=minval;
    for(k=0;k<10;k++)
    {
        if(A[i]>m && A[i]<(m+d))
        B[i]=k;

    }
    m+=d;

}

for (i=0; i<20; i++) 
{ 
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize"? It's not clear how the input corresponds to the desired output.

Comment: You have not specified what exactly is going wrong, but I bet it has to do with the fact that you are dividing integers. If the result is not an integer you **won't** automatically get a floating point number. To normalize change your array from `int` to `float` or `double`

Comment: Number 300 is the largest then it should be 10 in normalized form. -22 is the smallest then it should be 0 in normalized form etc..

Comment: @user3739434 and what with those in between?

Comment: First of all, you have 20 integers in your array but you want to "normalize" it in a range [0-10]. I didn't get it. Also, your second to the last for loop includes unnecessary assigning (`m+=d` which won't effect `A[i]<(m+d)` since `m` will be always `minval`) and unnecessary control (`A[i] > minval` where every element will return true but minimum value which is -22). So you may want to alter your code before explaining what your desired normalization process is.

Comment: Maybe I should make a new array to store them the "noramlization"  form.(I edited this)

Comment: still not clear how you normalize ... Looks really odd to me (200 and 300 both map to 10 ?)

Comment: basically linear interpolation with rounding. Find the largest and smallest values in the input. Anything between `min` and `min + 0.1(max-min)` is 0; anything between `min + 0.1(max-min)` and `min + 0.2(max-min)` is 1, ... anything between `min + 0.9(max-min)` and `max` is 10.

Comment: d=32 (average distance) Lowest number is -22 from -22 to (-22+32) belongs to 0.. from 10 to (10+32) belongs to 1.. form 42 to (42+32) belongs to 2.. from 74 to (74+32) belongs to 3.. from 106 to (106+32) belongs to 4.. etc

Comment: Clearly [-22:10] is 0, [10:42] is 1, [42:74] is 2, [74:106] is 3.. etc

Comment: @hobbs seems to have grasped your intent. Which way do you want to round -- down, up, or nearest?

Comment: @hobbs seems to have parsed the intent. It looks like a basic coordinate transformation he is seeking between a set ranging from -22 to 300 into an equivalent set ranging from 1 to 10. You may want to do the coordinate rotation into floats instead of int if you are concerned about rounding error.

Comment: `m+=d;` move to `for(k=0;k<10;k++, m+=d)` and `if(A[i]>m && A[i]<(m+d))` : There are elements that do not apply to conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* this is correct, but it's been over 20 years since I did this kind of integer math (on a minicomputer where integer math was the only kind of math you had).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /* Input data */
    int A[] = {
        -3, 200, -22, 4, 5, 300, 2, 5, 4, 5,
        -1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 4, 2, 0, 7, -3
    };
    int target_min = 0;
    int target_max = 10;

    /* Working variables */
    int nelems;
    int i;
    int source_min;
    int source_max;
    int source_scale;
    int target_scale;
    int zsrc;
    int scaled;

    nelems = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);

    source_min = source_max = A[0];
    for (i = 1; i < nelems; i++) {
        if (A[i] < source_min)
            source_min = A[i];
        if (A[i] > source_max)
            source_max = A[i];
    }

    if (source_min == source_max) {
        printf("Cannot scale: all values are the same\n");
        return -1;
    }

    source_scale = source_max - source_min;
    target_scale = target_max - target_min;

    /* The heart of the algorithm: scale everything.
       First, translate to a source_scale starting at zero.
       Second, scale to target_scale (also starting at zero).
       Third, translate to desired target scale.

       Scaling is done with integer math. Can round three ways; leave
       the desired one uncommented.
    */

    for (i = 0; i < nelems; i++) {
        zsrc = A[i] - source_min;

        // Round down
        //scaled = zsrc * target_scale / source_scale;

        // Round up
        //scaled = (zsrc * target_scale + source_scale - 1) / source_scale;

        // Round to nearest; if exactly halfway, rounds up
        scaled = (zsrc * target_scale * 2 + source_scale) / source_scale / 2;

        A[i] = scaled + target_min;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nelems; i++) {
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `scaled = ...`.  Note this good approach fails if `zsrc*target_scale*2 + source_scale` overflows, which is fairly easy to do with various `int` values.  Maybe `(uintmax_t) 2 * zsrc * target_scale + source_scale`.